# ElasticSearch - HighLight multiple words and phrase

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight, nest

I need to highlight multiple words and phrases in a text with ElasticSearch.

I know how to highlight words, I know how to highlight phrases, but I'm not able to combine both requests.

This is my query for higlighting a phrase :

```
 "query": {
    "match": {
       "ar_article.search": {
         "type": "phrase",
         "query": "trimestre 2016"
          }
      }
  }
```

Can someone helps me ?

Thank's

Comment: By "hightlight" do you mean search or ES [hightlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) feature?

Comment: I need to know how to combine search requests. No problem for highlighting.

Comment: Please, post the complete query